# JSon/SQL Project - (NHL Score & Logos) Only Missing Logos

Tags: php, sql, json, postgresql

OK.

*Scenario:* 
I have used https://www.mysportsfeeds.com to download a JSON file with NHL matches. 
The JSON file contains the Team Name as well as Results. With the content I have created a table that looks like this. Json file looks like this : http://stephaniie.com/scoreboard.json

```
    scoreboard: {
lastUpdatedOn: "2017-04-17 9:23:44 AM",
gameScore: [
{
game: {
ID: "40295",
date: "2017-04-16",
time: "3:00PM",
awayTeam: {
ID: "25",
City: "Minnesota",
Name: "Wild",
Abbreviation: "MIN"
},
homeTeam: {
ID: "17",
City: "St. Louis",
Name: "Blues",
Abbreviation: "STL"
},
location: "Scottrade Center"
},
isUnplayed: "false",
isInProgress: "false",
isCompleted: "true",
awayScore: "1",
awayShots: "41",
homeScore: "3",
homeShots: "31",
periodSummary: {
period: [
{
@number: "1",
awayScore: "0",
awayShots: "9",
homeScore: "1",
homeShots: "15"
},
{
@number: "2",
awayScore: "1",
awayShots: "13",
homeScore: "1",
homeShots: "8"
},
{
@number: "3",
awayScore: "0",
awayShots: "19",
homeScore: "1",
homeShots: "8"
}
]
}
},
{
game: {
ID: "40287",
date: "2017-04-16",
time: "6:00PM",
awayTeam: {
ID: "10",
City: "Pittsburgh",
Name: "Penguins",
Abbreviation: "PIT"
},
homeTeam: {
ID: "19",
City: "Columbus",
Name: "Blue Jackets",
Abbreviation: "CBJ"
},
location: "Nationwide Arena"
},
isUnplayed: "false",
isInProgress: "false",
isCompleted: "true",
awayScore: "5",
awayShots: "47",
homeScore: "4",
homeShots: "37",
periodSummary: {
period: [
{
@number: "1",
awayScore: "1",
awayShots: "11",
homeScore: "3",
homeShots: "14"
},
{
@number: "2",
awayScore: "2",
awayShots: "19",
homeScore: "0",
homeShots: "8"
},
{
@number: "3",
awayScore: "1",
awayShots: "10",
homeScore: "1",
homeShots: "8"
},
{
@number: "4",
awayScore: "1",
awayShots: "7",
homeScore: "0",
homeShots: "7"
}
]
}
},
{
game: {
ID: "40275",
date: "2017-04-16",
time: "7:00PM",
awayTeam: {
ID: "14",
City: "Montreal",
Name: "Canadiens",
Abbreviation: "MTL"
},
homeTeam: {
ID: "9",
City: "New York",
Name: "Rangers",
Abbreviation: "NYR"
},
location: "Madison Square Gardens"
},
isUnplayed: "false",
isInProgress: "false",
isCompleted: "true",
awayScore: "3",
awayShots: "29",
homeScore: "1",
homeShots: "21",
periodSummary: {
period: [
{
@number: "1",
awayScore: "0",
awayShots: "10",
homeScore: "0",
homeShots: "6"
},
{
@number: "2",
awayScore: "1",
awayShots: "12",
homeScore: "0",
homeShots: "6"
},
{
@number: "3",
awayScore: "2",
awayShots: "7",
homeScore: "1",
homeShots: "9"
}
]
}
},
{
game: {
ID: "40303",
date: "2017-04-16",
time: "10:00PM",
awayTeam: {
ID: "24",
City: "Edmonton",
Name: "Oilers",
Abbreviation: "EDM"
},
homeTeam: {
ID: "26",
City: "San Jose",
Name: "Sharks",
Abbreviation: "SJS"
},
location: "SAP Center"
},
isUnplayed: "false",
isInProgress: "false",
isCompleted: "true",
awayScore: "1",
awayShots: "22",
homeScore: "0",
homeShots: "23",
periodSummary: {
period: [
{
@number: "1",
awayScore: "0",
awayShots: "6",
homeScore: "0",
homeShots: "13"
},
{
@number: "2",
awayScore: "0",
awayShots: "12",
homeScore: "0",
homeShots: "4"
},
{
@number: "3",
awayScore: "1",
awayShots: "4",
homeScore: "0",
homeShots: "6"
}
]
}
}
]
}
}
```

[image: a busy cat]

As you see, unfortunately, it does not contain the teams logos. And considering that this is a hobby project (non-commercial) thought to do in a slightly different way.

*Theory:* 
I have created a SQL table with NHL team name and hyperlinks to their logos. 
I have also created a database contact and use SELECT statements to retrieve data from the SQL table.

```
$ A_query = "SELECT * FROM nhl_team_logo ORDER BY ID" ;
$ A_result = pg_query ($ con, $ a_query) or the ( "Can not execute query: $ a_query \ n" );
```

Now, however, I come to a little uphill.

**Question:** 
How should I use logic to pair these two? (The Mysports FEED and the SQL Table)? 
Obviously, my natural idea is to create a link between the SQL database's "Alt-Logo" and the feed's "Away Team-Name" and "Home Team-Name" as both values are the same. However, I'm a bit uncertain how to logically write this.

Right now (with Mysport's Feed only), the HTML code looks like the following:

```
Table class = "table" >
<Tbody>
<? Php
Foreach ($ nhl ['scoreboard'] ['gameScore'] as $ game) {
Echo '<tr>';
Echo '<td> <img src = "images / used / sports / Untitled-3_13.png" alt = "W3Schools.com" style = "max-width: 80%" > </ td>';
Echo '<td>'. $ Game ['game'] ['away team'] ['name']. '</ Td>';
Echo '<td class = "bold" >'. $ Game ['awayScore']. '-'. $ Game ['homeScore']. '</ Td>';
Echo '<td>'. $ Game ['game'] ['homeTeam'] ['Name']. '</ Td>';
Echo '<td> <img src = "images / used / sports / Untitled-3_14.png" alt = "W3Schools.com" style = "max-width: 80%" > </ td>';
}?>
</ Tbody>
</ Table>
```

Can you help me?

Edit: Here's how the database looks ... SQL Postgres:

[image: a busy cat]

Answer..

A friend of mine Solved this. I provide adequate code. This is a rather long answer and the reason I provide it is.. 1. I want a good example to look for myself. So either way I'm gonna this copy. Reason is, Most Tutorials, Stackoverflows, etc, they provide alittle code but its just for the one function.. If you read a book you need the whole section , not just scrabled words. That's why a full-fletched understanding and also Code Snippet is essential to understand code if you don't and if you do. Well.. this wouldn't be any help if you're already experienced with this methods and functions.

So here I provide Code to create News Items and Sports Items from Feeds (XML and JSON). To Parse them. Create Arrays and also display them on the site + database connection tutorial is included . And also how to use SQL in co-junction with JSON to create a connection between the two. You are so Welcome!

Result will be something like this.

[image: test]

**1.** Create a Database connection. I use this in /config/db.php. Also don't care about you seeing my login credentials as its just on localhost.

DB.PHP

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbport = 5432;
$dbname = 'acme';
$dbuser = 'devuser';
$dbpass = '123456';

$con = pg_connect("host=".$dbhost." port=".$dbport.". 
    dbname=".$dbname." user=".$dbuser." password=".$dbpass);
```

**2.** Make a file for your XML RSS FEED Connection (I use NYT RSS Feed) . I call mine rss-feeds.php

RSS-FEEDS.PHP

```
<?php

    //Gets RSS FEEDs
    $url = "http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml"; // xmld.xml contains above data
    $feeds = file_get_contents($url);
    $rss = simplexml_load_string($feeds);

    //Creates Array
    $items = [];

    //Loop Feed Objects (images, description) into Array  as they are Media: tags and harder to get.
        foreach($rss->channel->item as $entry) {
        $image = '';
        $image = 'N/A';
        foreach ($entry->children('media', true) as $k => $v) {
            $attributes = $v->attributes();

            if (count($attributes) == 0) {
                continue;
            } else {
                $image = $attributes->url;
            }
        $content_data = (string)$entry->children("media", true)->description;
        $credit = (string)$entry->children("media", true)->credit;
        $creator = (string)$entry->children("dc", true)->creator;
        $pubDate = (string)$entry->pubDate;
        $pubDate = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $pubDate);


        }

        //Not sure.. guess it find the last two rss feed obects - Title and Link. 
        $items[] = [
            'link' => $entry->link,
            'title' => $entry->title,
            'image' => $image,
            'creator' =>$creator,
            'pubDate' =>$pubDate,
        ];

    }

?>
```

**3.** Make a file for your Sports JSON Connection (I use https://www.mysportsfeeds.com/) . I call mine sports-json.php. .

SPORTS-JSON.PHP

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = 'https://www.mysportsfeeds.com/api/feed/pull/nhl/2017-playoff/scoreboard.json?fordate=20170416';

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$nhl=json_decode($result,true);
curl_close($ch);


?>
```

**4.** In Index.php - (website) - Include DB, Sports Feed (json) and RSS FEED (XML) Make a Select Function for the SQL DB TABLE.. Im using Postgres.

```
<?php
include 'rss-feeds.php';
include 'sports-json.php'; 
include 'config/db.php'; //This is the database connection. 

 function getTeamLogos(){
    global $con;
    $logos = [];
    $a_query = "SELECT logo, team FROM nhl_team_logo;";
    $a_result = pg_query($con, $a_query) or die("Cannot execute");
    $placeholder_logo = 'placeholder.jpg';
    if(pg_num_rows($a_result ) > 0) {
        while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($a_result )) {
            $logos[$row['team']] = ($row['logo'] ? $row['logo'] : $placeholder_logo);
        }
    }
    return $logos;
}
?>
```

**5.** Finally, Use json,xml and sql in your (index.php) HTML code. I provide a sort of demonstration how to use each of these three.

**JSON and SQL:**

```
<?php $logos = getTeamLogos();?>
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<?php
   foreach ($nhl['scoreboard']['gameScore'] as $game) {
       echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td><img src="'.$logos[$game['game']['homeTeam']['Name']].'" alt="'.$game['game']['homeTeam']['Name'].'" style="max-width:80%"></td>'; 
      echo '<td>' . $game['game']['awayTeam']['Name'] . '</td>';
      echo '<td class="bold"> ' . $game['awayScore'] . ' - ' . $game['homeScore'] . ' </td>';
      echo '<td>' . $game['game']['homeTeam']['Name'] . '</td>';
      echo '<td><img src="images/used/sports/Untitled-3_14.png" alt="W3Schools.com" style="max-width:80%"></td>';
   } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**XML:**

```
<div class="col-sm-3" >
    <h2 class="rightnow-title ">Right Now</h2><hr>
    <?php $i2=0; 
    foreach ($items2 as $item2) {
        if ($i2 < 4) {
            printf('<div class="right-now-box">');
            printf('<img src="%s" class="width-100">', $item2['image2']);
            printf('<a target="_blank" class="rightnow-text" href="%s">%s</a>', $item2['link2'], $item2['title2']);
            printf('</div>');
            $i2++;
        }
    } ?>
</div>
```

**You** can also build IF statements with the XML code to use different design. 
Either by : Using another XML item number , just change foreach statement to this - `foreach(range(6, 15) as $i) {` //gives Item6 to 15.

or with different design - Just don't forget to use a " break " statement at the end to end the if loop.

```
<?php
   $i=0; 
   foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($i <= 0) {
      printf('<div class="top-news-flex-parent">');
      printf('<div class="top-news-item">');
      printf('<img class="sidebar-first-img" src="%s">', $item['image']);
      printf('<a target ="_blank" href="%s">%s</a><br>', $item ['link'], $item['title']);
      printf('<span class="reporter">%s</span><span class="date"></span>', $item['creator']);?> <span class="date"> <?php 
      echo  $item['pubDate'][1]; ?> <?php echo $item['pubDate'][2]; ?> <?php echo $item['pubDate'][3];
      printf('</div>');
      printf('</div>');
      $i++;
    } elseif ($i < 5) {
    if ($item['image'] == "N/A") {
        printf('<div class="top-news-flex-parent">');
        printf('<div class="top-news-item">');
        printf('<a href="%s">%s</a><br>', $item ['link'], $item['title']);
        ?> <span class="date"> <?php 
        printf('<span class="reporter">%s</span><span class="date"></span>', $item['creator']);
        echo $item['pubDate'][1]; ?> <?php echo $item['pubDate'][2]; ?> <?php echo $item['pubDate'][3];
        printf('</div>');
        printf('</div>');   
        $i++;
    } else {
        printf('<div class="top-news-flex-parent">');
        printf('<div class="top-news-imgtext" >');
        printf('<a href="%s">%s<a/><br>', $item ['link'], $item['title']);
        printf('<span class="reporter">%s</span><span class="date"></span>', $item['creator']);
        ?> <br><span class="date"> <?php 
        echo $item['pubDate'][1]; ?> <?php echo $item['pubDate'][2]; ?> <?php echo $item['pubDate'][3];
        printf('</div>');
        printf('<div class="top-news-img"><img src="%s"></div>', $item['image']);
        printf('</div>');
        $i++;
    }                           
    } else {
        break;
    }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the JSON file have any ID for each team? You could use this ID to relate to the IDs you defined in your table.

Another option is to generate a unique ID from the team name.

For example, you could convert the team name by transforming all letters to uppercase and replace spaces with underscores. Or you make an MD5 of the team name. One way or another, you could use this ID to match the two.

Comment: My idea is to make a LINK between SQL table ( alt-logo ) and JSON ( AWAYTEAM / HOMETEAM ) - as in .. SQL alt logo ( Ducks ) is also  JSON hometeam/awateam ( DUCKS ) . If these values match. Then create a new array which has all values of JSON ( awayteam, hometeam, homescore, awayscore ) and sql values ( image and full team name ) .

Comment: In simplier ways to describe. 
There is already a link. 
SQL has alt-logo which is identical to JSON's awayteam/hometeam. So the only thing im doing is adding a img link in the SQL table , and then gonna match it with the json file. 

But im not as experienced as i thought i was, so i need alittle help what to write to achieve this.

Comment: I cant use this as answer as it doesn't provide me with any information how to progress. No It doesn't have an ID is what i can . And sorry i forgot to post the json file previously.

Comment: What is the ID field inside awayTeam and homeTeam objects? Isn't the team ID?

Comment: Well.. JSON : $game['game']['homeTeam']['Name'] and SQL nhl_team_logo['alt-logo'] is already the same . Both gives a teams shorten name : as example.. Wild.. and SQL has that teams logo url as well in nhl_team_logo['logo']

Comment: And no. i not sure but looking at JSON code it seems it only provides 4 matches . not entire team info. i think.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine Solved this. I provide adequate code. This is a rather long answer and the reason I provide it is.. 1. I want a good example to look for myself. So either way I'm gonna this copy. Reason is, Most Tutorials, Stackoverflows, etc, they provide alittle code but its just for the one function.. If you read a book you need the whole section , not just scrabled words. That's why a full-fletched understanding and also Code Snippet is essential to understand code if you don't and if you do. When this wouldn't be any help for you either Way.

So here I provide Code to create News Items and Sports Items from Feeds (XML and JSON). To Parse them. Create Arrays and also display them on the site + database connection tutorial is included . And also how to use SQL in co-junction with JSON to create a connection between the two. You are so Welcome!

Result will be something like this.

[image: test]

**1.** Create a Database connection. I use this in /config/db.php. Also don't care about you seeing my login credentials as its just on localhost.

DB.PHP

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbport = 5432;
$dbname = 'acme';
$dbuser = 'devuser';
$dbpass = '123456';

$con = pg_connect("host=".$dbhost." port=".$dbport.". 
    dbname=".$dbname." user=".$dbuser." password=".$dbpass);
```

**2.** Make a file for your XML RSS FEED Connection (I use NYT RSS Feed) . I call mine rss-feeds.php

RSS-FEEDS.PHP

```
<?php

    //Gets RSS FEEDs
    $url = "http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml"; // xmld.xml contains above data
    $feeds = file_get_contents($url);
    $rss = simplexml_load_string($feeds);

    //Creates Array
    $items = [];

    //Loop Feed Objects (images, description) into Array  as they are Media: tags and harder to get.
        foreach($rss->channel->item as $entry) {
        $image = '';
        $image = 'N/A';
        foreach ($entry->children('media', true) as $k => $v) {
            $attributes = $v->attributes();

            if (count($attributes) == 0) {
                continue;
            } else {
                $image = $attributes->url;
            }
        $content_data = (string)$entry->children("media", true)->description;
        $credit = (string)$entry->children("media", true)->credit;
        $creator = (string)$entry->children("dc", true)->creator;
        $pubDate = (string)$entry->pubDate;
        $pubDate = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $pubDate);


        }

        //Not sure.. guess it find the last two rss feed obects - Title and Link. 
        $items[] = [
            'link' => $entry->link,
            'title' => $entry->title,
            'image' => $image,
            'creator' =>$creator,
            'pubDate' =>$pubDate,
        ];

    }

?>
```

**3.** Make a file for your Sports JSON Connection (I use https://www.mysportsfeeds.com/) . I call mine sports-json.php. .

SPORTS-JSON.PHP

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = 'https://www.mysportsfeeds.com/api/feed/pull/nhl/2017-playoff/scoreboard.json?fordate=20170416';

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$nhl=json_decode($result,true);
curl_close($ch);


?>
```

**4.** In Index.php - (website) - Include DB, Sports Feed (json) and RSS FEED (XML) Make a Select Function for the SQL DB TABLE.. Im using Postgres.

```
<?php
include 'rss-feeds.php';
include 'sports-json.php'; 
include 'config/db.php'; //This is the database connection. 

 function getTeamLogos(){
    global $con;
    $logos = [];
    $a_query = "SELECT logo, team FROM nhl_team_logo;";
    $a_result = pg_query($con, $a_query) or die("Cannot execute");
    $placeholder_logo = 'placeholder.jpg';
    if(pg_num_rows($a_result ) > 0) {
        while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($a_result )) {
            $logos[$row['team']] = ($row['logo'] ? $row['logo'] : $placeholder_logo);
        }
    }
    return $logos;
}
?>
```

**5.** Finally, Use json,xml and sql in your (index.php) HTML code. I provide a sort of demonstration how to use each of these three.

**JSON and SQL:**

```
<?php $logos = getTeamLogos();?>
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<?php
   foreach ($nhl['scoreboard']['gameScore'] as $game) {
       echo '<tr>';
       echo '<td><img src="'.$logos[$game['game']['homeTeam']['Name']].'" alt="'.$game['game']['homeTeam']['Name'].'" style="max-width:80%"></td>'; 
      echo '<td>' . $game['game']['awayTeam']['Name'] . '</td>';
      echo '<td class="bold"> ' . $game['awayScore'] . ' - ' . $game['homeScore'] . ' </td>';
      echo '<td>' . $game['game']['homeTeam']['Name'] . '</td>';
      echo '<td><img src="images/used/sports/Untitled-3_14.png" alt="W3Schools.com" style="max-width:80%"></td>';
   } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**XML:**

```
<div class="col-sm-3" >
    <h2 class="rightnow-title ">Right Now</h2><hr>
    <?php $i2=0; 
    foreach ($items2 as $item2) {
        if ($i2 < 4) {
            printf('<div class="right-now-box">');
            printf('<img src="%s" class="width-100">', $item2['image2']);
            printf('<a target="_blank" class="rightnow-text" href="%s">%s</a>', $item2['link2'], $item2['title2']);
            printf('</div>');
            $i2++;
        }
    } ?>
</div>
```

**You** can also build IF statements with the XML code to use different design. 
Either by : Using another XML item number , just change foreach statement to this - foreach(range(6, 15) as $i) { //gives Item6 to 15.

or with different design - Just don't forget to use a " break " statement at the end to end the if loop.

```
<?php
   $i=0; 
   foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($i <= 0) {
      printf('<div class="top-news-flex-parent">');
      printf('<div class="top-news-item">');
      printf('<img class="sidebar-first-img" src="%s">', $item['image']);
      printf('<a target ="_blank" href="%s">%s</a><br>', $item ['link'], $item['title']);
      printf('<span class="reporter">%s</span><span class="date"></span>', $item['creator']);?> <span class="date"> <?php 
      echo  $item['pubDate'][1]; ?> <?php echo $item['pubDate'][2]; ?> <?php echo $item['pubDate'][3];
      printf('</div>');
      printf('</div>');
      $i++;
    } elseif ($i < 5) {
    if ($item['image'] == "N/A") {
        printf('<div class="top-news-flex-parent">');
        printf('<div class="top-news-item">');
        printf('<a href="%s">%s</a><br>', $item ['link'], $item['title']);
        ?> <span class="date"> <?php 
        printf('<span class="reporter">%s</span><span class="date"></span>', $item['creator']);
        echo $item['pubDate'][1]; ?> <?php echo $item['pubDate'][2]; ?> <?php echo $item['pubDate'][3];
        printf('</div>');
        printf('</div>');   
        $i++;
    } else {
        printf('<div class="top-news-flex-parent">');
        printf('<div class="top-news-imgtext" >');
        printf('<a href="%s">%s<a/><br>', $item ['link'], $item['title']);
        printf('<span class="reporter">%s</span><span class="date"></span>', $item['creator']);
        ?> <br><span class="date"> <?php 
        echo $item['pubDate'][1]; ?> <?php echo $item['pubDate'][2]; ?> <?php echo $item['pubDate'][3];
        printf('</div>');
        printf('<div class="top-news-img"><img src="%s"></div>', $item['image']);
        printf('</div>');
        $i++;
    }                           
    } else {
        break;
    }
} ?>
```